# business family or business class family

Tags: adjectives

I know that there is no adjective form for business, if I wanted to say that I live in a family whose traditional job is business. which of the following sentence would be correct?

1- I was born and have been living all my life in a business family.

2- I was born and have been living all my life in a business class family.

Comment: #1 is better, but I'd use present perfect simple (have lived) with "all my life"  Business class family also sounds like you have expensive taste in airline tickets.Otherwise Andrew has explained it well.

Comment: The single-word form in *He's a businessman* is fine, but I don't much like the adjectival usage *a business family* - I'd rather see something more explicit, such as *a **business-oriented** family*. And *business **class** family* just sounds like a clumsy form based on usages like *a working-class family*.

Comment: To my BrE ears, "a business class family" sounds like a family that's sufficiently wealthy to afford "business class" airline tickets. Which is not to be sniffed at, but is not what you're attempting to say.

Comment: It's unclear to me whether you are interested in identifying the family's occupation or its social standing. If the former, as Andrew notes, one would likely indicate the type of business, or the industry. If the latter, however, there are a number of different terms with different connotations, such as being in the *merchant class* or *mercantile class* (as distinguished from the workers and the landowners) or the *bourgeoisie* (a borrowing from French and popularized in Marxist literature, and thus frequently disparaging).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to talk about the "family business" in a generic way:

> I grew up working in the **family business**

However, "business" by itself is often too ambiguous to tell the reader anything interesting about your family.  Instead, it's natural to be specific about the kind of business your family does.  Some examples:

> Our family business is **textiles**.
>
> Our family has a large share of the **textile market**.
>
> Our family is big in **textiles**.

You can substitute whatever details are appropriate:

> I grew up in a family whose business was making shoes / selling cars / international finance / technology / shipping and trade / etc.

Side note:  I use "was" to talk about the family business rather than "is".  This should not be interpreted to mean that the family is now "out of business".  It simply refers to the past time period "when I was growing up".  The family business could be doing just fine.

If you want to be clear that the family is still in the same business, you can instead use "is"

> I grew up in a family whose business **is** making shoes

[Edit]  The expression "business class" is not used outside of travel.  If you mean to distinguish your family as something other than "working class", then the only distinction in common use is "upper class".  Many upper class families own one or more *businesses* as their source of income, but it's their wealth that makes them upper class.

If you want to refer to the social class of people who own businesses (in something like an economic or political treatise) then there is the term *bourgeoisie*, borrowed from the French, which can specifically refer to the class of society which owns the means of production.  It is not, however, normally perceived as a complimentary term.

Comment: A family business is a specific company that's owned and primarily operated by members of a single family. A business family is a family whose members are mostly in business, but they don't have to be in the same company.

Comment: @Barmar    I searched and found a very few references that use the phrase "business family", but in each the reference defined it to have a particular meaning distinct from "family business".  In my opinion, without explanation, it has no special meaning -- much like "business" itself, which is essentially meaningless until defined.

Comment: That's true -- business is so general that the idea of a "business family" is unlikely. Contrast it with farming family, police family, medical family: these are relatively specific, and it's common for children to follow their parents' footsteps in them.

Comment: OTOH, the Trumps could be considered a business family.

Answer (score 1):

If I captured your intent, I would say "a business-oriented family" or 'family of business-people."